# How to connect 2 VMware instance running on same Linux host machine via emulated ethernet cable (accessible via mac address)?

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, virtual-machine, ethernet, vmware

I have a host machine running Linux (ubuntu-18.04). There I have 2 VMware instances configured and the network is configured via NAT. I can ping from VM1 to VM2 (and vice-versa) via their local IPs but for my current need, I want them to be connected via ethernet cable for the DPDK test environment so that one machine can find another by direct mac address(layer 2 protocol, without IP stack).
How to do that in an easy and efficient way and test that it is working (via arping probably, not sure) correctly?

Comment: To be clear, what you're asking is how connect two *virtual* computers with a *physical* ethernet cable?

Comment: no, emulating a ethernet cable behaviour

Answer (score 3):

If you need *physical* Layer-2 connectivity, then you need to use the bridged mode, not NAT.

Note that you cannot use bridged mode on wireless networks unless your host OS is also the wireless Access Point. When your host is a wireless client, it has just a single WiFi identity (MAC address + associated encryption session keys), and if it tries to bridge VMs' traffic into the wireless network, the combination of the VM's MAC address + the host's WiFi encryption keys just gets rejected by the access point.

For Layer-2 connectivity *between VMs in the same host*, you just need to make sure all the VMs have their virtual NICs using the same virtual switch. [See this page in VMware Workstation documentation](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Player-for-Windows/17.0/com.vmware.player.win.using.doc/GUID-89311E3D-CCA9-4ECC-AF5C-C52BE6A89A95.html): multiple VMs can virtually plug in to the same virtual switch and communicate freely with each other even in NAT mode, as the NAT element is just between the virtual switch and the physical networks outside the host.

In NAT mode, the default virtual switch is going to be named `VMnet8`. All VMs that have been connected to that virtual switch will automatically have Layer-2 connectivity between each other.

Testing that can be a bit tricky, however. A network interface will only answer to incoming ARP requests if it has an IP address configured, so you'll need to configure IP addresses (at least temporarily) if you wish to test with `arping`.

There does not seem to be a pure Layer-2 connectivity tester available in RHEL 8 at this time. However, in the past I've used [this utility](https://github.com/fancer/linkloop): note that you'll have to install it on both VMs, run `linkloopd` on one VM and test using the `linkloop` command on the other VM.

Comment: I tried the bridge but got confused. my host machine has 1 interface "wlo1" which is running private ip "192.168.19.217" and another interface "eno1" has no ip but just ethernet address. I tried VM1/VM2 network to be configured with bridge mode and connected to eno1/wlo1 interface. But then how can I be sure that now VM1 and VM2 are now connected via emulated ethernet cable and they can find each other via mac address...?? Thanks for the info..!

Comment: Oh, so you just need a *virtual* cable connection? See my edit above.

Comment: I used VM before but not much idea about virtual switch. From searching I came to know that Open vSwitch is popular in this area, so I need to install open vswitch first on host machine and connect those 2 VM to that? how to do that actually, or feel free to suggest docs or software to create switch-host connected environment.

Comment: No, VMware should have its own virtual switch(es) as standard, so you won't need Open vSwitch for anything. Basically, if you use VMware's default settings and configure both your two VMs to use NAT-mode networking, they should automatically be connected to the VMnet8 virtual switch, and so would have a direct Layer-2 connectivity with each other and connectivity through a NAT to the outside world. (For more details, please identify your VMware version: Workstation Player, Workstation Pro, or something else?)

Comment: Is this the same for KVM? as my goal is to implement it in KVM(QEMU emulator version 2.11.1). I tried using NAT/Bridge for both VMs. Then I tried to send data from VM1(using DPDK which needs layer2 connection) to VM2 (normal receiver) but it failed anyway...

Comment: Please post a separate Question for that (and specify the name and version of the distribution you'll be setting KVM up in, as details might vary). I'm more used to VMware, but I think KVM would work essentially the same as long as both VMs would be assigned to the same Linux bridge instance. A separate question with a more appropriate title would better get noticed by the people more knowledgeable in KVM/QEMU setups than me.